# Group data monthly and city

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have written a query to get this data, but this data is based from today to 22-01-2016.

I want to write it in a way that it should show the values for January, then February as I want to see how much TotalCredit is being increased monthly.

Please view the data as image

Comment: I think you are looking for `GROUP BY MONTH(Date)`

Comment: But how will that also GROUP BY City

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    City,
    Sum(Violations) AS TotalViolations,
    SUM(USDSpent) AS 'TotalCredit(USD)'
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            city. NAME AS City,
            count(user_credit.booking_id) AS Violations,
            Round(SUM(amount / usd_rate_to), 1) AS USDSpent,
            user_credit.creation_date AS Date
        FROM
            user_credit
        JOIN booking ON user_credit.booking_id = booking.id
        JOIN booking_detail ON booking.id = booking_detail.booking_id
        JOIN drivers ON booking_detail.assigned_driver_id = drivers.id
        JOIN limo_company ON drivers.limo_company_id = limo_company.id
        JOIN city ON limo_company.city_id = city.id
        JOIN customer_car_type cct ON booking.customer_car_type_id = cct.id
        JOIN service_area ON cct.service_area_id = service_area.id
        JOIN currency_exchange ON user_credit.base_currency_exchange_id = currency_exchange.id
        WHERE
            user_credit.creation_date BETWEEN SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
        AND NOW()
        GROUP BY
            Date
    ) AS tableA
GROUP BY    City,month(creation_date)
```

Comment: Gives me an error - Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'user_credit.creation_date' in 'group statement'

Comment: group by city, month( user_credit.creation_date )

replace this statement at last line of the query
please reply if still an error

Comment: GROUP BY    City,month(tableA.Date)

Comment: This works, but what is does it, just shows city two times. I want to display, for January, February.

Comment: remove city from group by clause

group by month(tableA.date)

Comment: user_credit.creation_date BETWEEN SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND NOW() 

Doesn't this line need to be changed, as this is looking back at 30 days from today, but I want to consider January as a month and then February

Comment: WHERE
            user_credit.creation_date BETWEEN date_sub(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
        AND NOW()
        GROUP BY
            date_format(Date,'%b')